# Go convert to float from string which represent binary

Tags: arrays, go, binary, byte, grpc

Go gRPC metadata, get and convert the value.

In my logs, i saw that the metadata was being translated into another type (I think it's a byte array) like this

```
"latitude-bin":"\ufffd\u0019\u0014\ufffd\ufffdϑL","longitude-bin":"@Z\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u000e\ufffdD"
```

Both of those value should be a Double if I'm not mistaken.
I want to convert those value into a `Double` or `float64` in Golang, but I'm a bit unsure about my approach, since I don't know the type of `latitude-bin` or `longitude-bin` and I can't reproduce those value (taken from the logs by my clients)

Here is my approach

```
// GetLangitute get latitude from metadata `latitude-bin` and return nil when fails
func GetLangitute(ctx context.Context) *float64 {
    metadataList := getMetaDataListByKey(ctx, latitudeBin)
    if metadataList != nil {
        s := metadataList[metadataIndex]
        b := []byte(s)
        // TODO: 
        // I'm still a bit unsure about this approach
        data := math.Float64frombits(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(b))
        return &data
    }

    return nil
}

func getMetaDataListByKey(ctx context.Context, key string) []string {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }

    metadataList := md.Get(key)
    if isEmpty(metadataList) {
        return nil
    }

    return metadataList
}

func isEmpty(metadataList []string) bool {
    return len(metadataList) == 0
}
```

I tried to test using a Unit Test and look good, but still I'm unsure about the expected result since I can't reproduce it, here is my Unit test

```
f := math.Float64frombits(uint64(6662343813755067509))
// ...
name: "Given key exist in metadata",
            args: args{
                ctx: metadata.NewIncomingContext(
                    context.Background(),
                    metadata.Pairs("latitude-bin", `\ufffd\u0019\u0014\ufffd\ufffdϑL`),
                ),
            },
            want: &f,
// ...
t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
    got := GetLangitute(tt.args.ctx)
    if tt.want != nil {
        if *got != *tt.want {
            t.Errorf("GetLangitute() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
        }
    } else {
        assert.Nil(t, got)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems your input JSON is already "screwed". Your latitude and longitude values in JSON are 8-byte values, but they don't represent the original values. The original value is lost.

Go stores strings as their UTF-8 encoded byte sequence. When converting other types to string (e.g. `int`), when invalid values are encountered, the conversion will result in the Unicode replacement character `0xFFFD`.

Your input contains multiple of these runes: `\ufffd`. This means the encoding algorithm that produces your input JSON is faulty and resulted in information loss. It's unlikely you can reproduce the original latitude and longitude values.

You must fix the encoding part of your source.

Note: if your input would be valid / correct, you could simply convert the `string` value to `[]byte` like this:

```
b := []byte(s)
```

The above conversion would result in the bytes of `s`, regardless whether `s` contains valid UTF-8 sequence or not.

Comment: You are right, seems like there is something intercepts the value. I talked to the FE team and they sent us the value like this `41cdcd6500000000`

They gave us how to generate those value using Kotlin, And I noticed that the values are different compared to server logs

Comment: Here is the how-to generate the value from the client (Kotlin) https://pl.kotl.in/kte_JvwIA